# Wordpress page clean from theme JS and CSS

Tags: php, html, wordpress

A client has requested that I place an html file on their Wordpress site, but I'm having trouble accomplishing this. The html file contains custom css and javascript in addition to custom meta tags. So if I just copy and paste the contents of the file into a page, it will obviously conflict with CSS and JS loaded by Wordpress. I would like add an add_action function to recognize the page I want custom html on and then only load that and not any Wordpress or theme data.

This is as far as I have gotten on my own.

```
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'toggle_theme', 1);
    function toggle_theme() {
      global $post;
      $slug = $post->post_name;

      if($slug = 'dream-vacation') {

      }
    }
```

I have been able to recognize the page I want to customize, but I can't figure out how to make it a clean page and load up the custom html I need.

Comment: Could a solution be to just upload the HTML file through FTP to the root of their server?

Comment: I would think, but how do I link to the file and keep the desired url structure of www.domain.com/custom-page?

Comment: Tough question. You may be able to do this through your Apache or Nginx settings to strip out the file extension. Perhaps a plugin like this would do the work for you though. https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-html-bodyhead/

Comment: I just went with the iframe route for now. Not clean, but effective.

Answer (score 1):

Stop loading the page with WordPress.

Delete WordPress page with `/dream-vacation/` slug.

Save page as `/dream-vacation/index.html`